# CORS Access-Control-Allow-Origin is working on GET not POST

Tags: ajax, cors

I tried to solve the problem of Access-Control-Allow-Origin by using CORS Filter http://software.dzhuvinov.com/cors-filter-installation.html.
I follow the instruction and it works only GET not POST. I have Java servlet on Tomcat server and I call this servlet via my web application, the code is here:

```
        var url = "http://server_url:8080/"
            + "gtpapi/testPlan/guid_" + planId + "/packages/" + packId + "/results";
        $.ajax({
            contentType : 'application/json',
            type : "POST",
            crossDomain: true,
            url : url,
            data : JSON.stringify(postData),
            async : false,
            dataType : 'json',
            error : function(XMLHttpRequest) {
                throw XMLHttpRequest.statusText;
            }
        });
```

And here is my web.xml of web server.

```
<filter>
    <!-- The CORS filter with parameters -->
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter</filter-class>

    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.allowOrigin</param-name>
        <param-value>*</param-value>
    </init-param>
     <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedMethods</param-name>
        <param-value>GET, HEAD, POST, OPTIONS</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportedHeaders</param-name>
        <param-value>Origin, Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-value>
   </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>cors.supportsCredentials</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <!-- CORS Filter mapping -->
    <filter-name>CORS</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/gtpapi/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I tried many ways all day but nothing works so far. 
I also tried either "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" to header or create CORSFilter class as this link http://padcom13.blogspot.fr/2011/09/cors-filter-for-java-applications.html. But it doesn't work for me at all. Any ideas?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've worked with it, but I think one thing I found with cross-origin is that the wildcard allow-origin never quite seemed to work as perfectly as specifically returning the origin domain, ie example.com. (You can retrieve this on the second server with the request's "Origin" header.) Maybe you could just try it out, and see if anything changes.

Comment: Can you provide the request/response headers of the failing response? These can be found in Chrome Console's Network tab.

Comment: @monsur 
Request URL:http://server_url:8080/gtpapi/testPlan/guid_00145E5BB8C21EE286A007464A64508C/packages/001999C5F62B1EE291BDFCEFF242089E/results
Request Method:OPTIONS
Status Code:200 OK
Request Headersview source
Accept:*/*
Accept-Charset:UTF-8,*;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,fr;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, origin, content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive

Comment: @monsur Host:server_url:8080
Origin:http://localhost:8080
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:http://localhost:8080/LTST_Frontend/index.html
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
Response Headersview source
Allow:POST,GET,OPTIONS,HEAD
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/xml
Date:Tue, 16 Jul 2013 08:28:27 GMT
Server:Apache-Coyote/1.1

Comment: I am having a similar issue with a Spring application on Tomcat. I use a REST API which has a CORS filter on it. I call the API from a JS UI and am having a similar problem. POST requests work for me but only on the second try. With two successive POST requests the first one successfully goes to the server and executes but does not return a response. When the second one executes then the server sends the response for the second POST but never the first one.

Comment: I have the same issue with my Alfresco DMS (based on Spring, Tomcat). Same CORS config as you, it also works fine with some POST methods and all GET methods, but for some POST methods (which urls also fall under the filter mapping urls) it does not work.